# How to get the list of followers from an Instagram account without getting banned?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instaloader

I am trying to scrape all the followers of some particular Instagram accounts. I am using Python 3.8.3 and the latest version of Instaloader library. The code I have written is given below:

```
# Import the required libraries:
import instaloader
import time
from random import randint

# Start time:
start = time.time()

# Create an instance of instaloader:
loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Credentials & target account:
user_id = USERID
password = PASSWORD
target = TARGET # Account of which the list of followers need to be scraped;

# Login or load the session:
loader.login(user_id, password)

# Obtain the profile metadata of the target:
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context, target)

# Print the list of followers and save it in a text file:
try:

    # The list to store the collected user handles of the followers:
    followers_list = []

    # Variables used to apply pauses to slow down scraping:
    count = 0 
    short_counter = 1
    short_pauser = randint(19, 24)
    long_counter = 1
    long_pauser = randint(4900, 5000)

    # Fetch the followers one by one:
    for follower in profile.get_followers():

        sleeper = randint(840, 1020)
    
        # Short pause for the process:
        if (short_counter % short_pauser == 0):
            short_counter = 0
            short_pauser = randint(19, 24)
            print('\nShort Pause.\n')
            time.sleep(1)

        # Long pause for the process:
        if (long_counter % long_pauser == 0):
            long_counter = 0
            long_pauser = randint(4900, 5000)
            print('\nLong pause.\n')
            time.sleep(sleeper)
        
        # Append the list and print the follower's user handle:
        followers_list.append(follower.username)
        print(count,'', followers_list[count])
    
        # Increment the counters accordingly:
        count = count + 1
        short_counter = short_counter + 1
        long_counter = long_counter + 1

    # Store the followers list in a txt file:
    txt_file = target + '.txt'
    with open(txt_file, 'a+') as f:
        for the_follower in followers_list:
            f.write(the_follower)
            f.write('\n')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# End time:
end = time.time()

total_time = end - start

# Print the time taken for execution:
print('Time taken for complete execution:', total_time,'s.')
```

I am getting the following error after scraping some data:

```
HTTP Error 400 (Bad Request) on GraphQL Query. Retrying with shorter page length.
HTTP Error 400 (Bad Request) on GraphQL Query. Retrying with shorter page length.
400 Bad Request
```

In fact, the error occurs when Instagram detects unusual activity and disables the account for a while and prompts the user to change the password.

I have tried -

(1) Slowing down the process of scraping.

(2) Adding pauses in between in order to make the program more human-like.

Still, no progress.

How to bypass such restrictions and get the complete list of all the followers?
If getting the entire list is not possible, what is the best way to get at least 20,000 followers list (from multiple accounts) without getting banned / disabled account / facing such inconveniences?